# reading logs in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

after launching your app on google app engine.
you can use the 'logs' page in the admin console to see a how many requests were made, 
any http:// 404 errors etc.

It's hard to make sense of how many visitors you really got and or others.

Am I missing something here ? 
Can somebody tell me how to read logs on a google app engine.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download request logs in Apache log format [using the appcfg tool](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs).

Answer (score 3):

The logs are not meant to control site visits. For that you should use [google analytics](http://analytics.google.com).

Comment: Google analytics means I need to add javascript and others. 
I might not want to do that.
 I think the google app engine is a bit weak if that is the only option.

Comment: You can certainly have your application do the same sort of stuff Analytics does in the backend, but reading the raw logs is unlikely to be at all useful.  And you're not going to do it as well as Google will do it for you, despite the massive effort it will take to program.

Comment: @lorenzo You can code something like analytics manually, but it doesn't make much sense. What's wrong with using javascript if it's a web app? Anyway you can always use Analytics without javascript: http://www.vdgraaf.info/google-analytics-without-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

In essence, google kinda expects you to use Google Analytics (being it their tool :-) )

What you could do however, is add some kind of loggin, where you'd simply write to a text-file, or call some kind of webservice that would do it for you.

Cheers